# Software for Windows that is able to truncate files on the fly whilst they are created

Tags: windows, batch

I'm doing data recovery and sometimes the found **files have an absurd huge size** (either because of damages in the file system, bugs in the software or the absense of a trailing signature).

Recovered folders and files are copied **in batch** (e.g. whole folder tree) to a target location.

I'm looking for a software that would act like a virtual drive, **intercept the data flow, let folders unchanged, trim huge files on the fly and write them to a predefined folder**. It would also generate some "copy successful" callback event as soon as each (truncated) file was written, so that the software the files originate from is informed about the successful copy completion and jumps to the next file to copy.

I assume that in Linux this could be done by chaining commands with the pipe  operator (`|`). I'm looking for an equivalent Windows solution, if possible one that is simple to use.

**Detailed scenario:**

1. One wants to copy a batch of files from data recovery software to some location. (e.g. `D:\TARGET\`)
2. The trimming software appears as drive `E:`  (or some valid location)
3. From the data recovery software, we ask to copy all files to `E:`
4. The trimming software let pass small files through, redirecting them to `D:\TARGET\`. It does the same for large files but trim them to a given threshold, whilst preserving the file name. The file structure is preserved as well.
5. Once a (truncated) file was copied to `D:\TARGET` the trimmer software generate a callback event (--I assume a Windows event--) to inform the data recovery software that the file was successfully copied on `E:`.

---

Solutions that work on a per file basis (without batch support) are also welcome, but please mention this limitation.

Comment: Quite special scenario. I doubt such a thing exists. Why not simply run the backup software twice? Run it once for a file size <=n MB, then run it again for files >n MB.

Comment: Not a backup software but a data recovery one. It has search features that allow to do what you suggested. However, some files may have an excessive size, like 1GB for a simple graphic file or 50 GB for a video. If you copy all of them, firstly it takes lot of time, secondly, together they may exceed the target storage size. Such file may arise if the data recovery software uses file carving techniques and no trailing signature is available for the file. Some files may be valid (even if truncated) if their sectors are contiguous. Simply because natively, they don't have a trailing signature.